# Spring Cloud Consul Configuration Versioning

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul, consul-kv

I am trying to figure out **how are you supposed to be versioning the Consul configurations.**

**My goal is to be able to prepare the production configurations for the next version without touching the existing ones.** And also to be able to revert to the old configurations if I downgrade.

### My first and only solution is to use the `spring.cloud.consul.config.data-key`

By default `data-key=data`, so the configurations would be:

```
config/testApp,dev/data
config/testApp/data
config/application,dev/data
config/application/data
```

I can change the key to be `data-key=v1`:

```
config/testApp,dev/v1
config/testApp/v1
config/application,dev/v1
config/application/v1
```

And on every configuration change, I will increment the version and everything should be fine.

### But my idea breaks when there are many applications sharing the `config/application*` configurations

Maybe the solution is to not version the application configurations which is probably not possible with the current version of Spring Cloud Consul.
**Or maybe even not having common configurations at all?**

**Am I on the right track?
Do I need to version my Consul configurations?
How do you manage them?**

Answer (score 1):

It will easy if you check-in  those config(production) in separate repository for example config_DEV, Config_Stage, Config_PROD maintain your repository based on which env it will get deployed.